# xamarin forms: how to make native login with facebook [ios]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

in xamarin forms i've succesfully make the facebook login in android with this tutorial

[Xamarin forms facebook login android](http://bytesizebits.blogspot.it/2017/02/xamarinforms-facebook-native-sdk-login.html)

Anyone has a tutorial to make native login in ios with xamarin forms? I know that i have to make a custom renderer, but i don't know the exact code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Xamarin.Auth component. Here is the step by step process and code.
https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.auth

Answer (score 0):

See here [Native login](https://dotnetco.de/native-facebook-login-in-xamarin-forms-ios-app/)

Then you could make a native login button as Mike James does [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/native-facebook-authentication-with-azure-app-service/)